# is there a jquery plugin that displays something like microsoft wizard?

Tags: jquery

do you remember a cute wizard that appears that guides you through a website ? i remember this from before, was wondering if such alternative exists for jquery.

the Actual Wizard character or Clippy that appears ! **not a wizard form !**

Comment: Side note: the wizard's name is Merlin (or at least that's his name in the Microsoft Agent ActiveX control).

Answer (score 2):

[clippy.js](https://www.smore.com/clippy-js) shall provide! You get the Clippy, Merlin (your wizard), Rover (the dog) and Links (the cat).

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search revealed this:

- [Jquery Wizard Plugin](http://worcesterwideweb.com/2007/06/04/jquery-wizard-plugin/)
- [Demo](http://worcesterwideweb.com/jquery/wizard/)